# OnBase - Find Keyword with VBScript

Tags: collections, vbscript, keyword-search

I've been struggling with trying to find a Keyword in OnBase with VBScript.  I'm not sure of the method to find and get the value based on the Keyword

This is what I have so far

```
'Keywords to Get
Const KEYWORD_VENDORNO = "Vendor Number"

Sub Main
   'Create Application Object
    Dim objApplication
    Set objApplication = CreateObject("OnBase.Application")

    'Get the current document
    Dim objCurrentDocument
    Set objCurrentDocument = objApplication.CurrentDocument

    'Get Collection of Keywords
    Dim colKeywords
    Set colKeywords = objCurrentDocument.Keywords

    'Set Keyword in memory
    colKeywords.AddKeyword(KEYWORD_VENDORNO,"123")
    'Save Keyword
    objCurrentDocument.StoreKeywords


    'Get Keyword - This is the part I don't know how to get.  I can't seem to find the 'right property or method to get the value of the keyword
'I've tried all the following, but none seem to work.  The only one that doesn't give me an 'error is the 2nd one, but it also doesn't give me a value
     msgbox colKeywords(0)
     msgbox colKeywords(KEYWORD_VENDORNO)
     msgbox colKeywords.GetKeyword(KEYWORD_VENDORNO)
     msgbox colKeywords.FindKeyword(KEYWORD_VENDORNO)
     msgbox objCurrentDocument.GetKeyword(KEYWORD_VENDORNO)
     msgbox objCurrentDocument.FindKeyword(KEYWORD_VENDORNO)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched the [OnBase Community](https://www.onbase.com/community) for help? There is a lot of great resources there.

I did a quick search for "VB Keyword" and found [this post](https://www.onbase.com/community/technical_communities/onbase_apis/f/10812/t/13214.aspx) asking about a document handle in VB Script. The answer was:

> *Try removing the "set" from before "documentHandle = document.Handle".*

This is supported by [this post](https://www.onbase.com/community/technical_communities/onbase_apis/f/10812/t/13872.aspx) that has examples WITHOUT the SET prefix.

Try dropping the ***SET*** prefix.